# MySQL PDO fetchAll as array with format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetchall

I have this PDO code

```
function getAllUserTicketHistoryJson($rid){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, total_ticket FROM lottery_user WHERE round_id = :rou");
    $stmt->bindParam(':rou', $rid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $res;
}
```

and show the data in my index php file like this one

```
$getAllUserTicketHistoryJson = getAllUserTicketHistoryJson($getRound['id']);
```

And call all the data to this one

```
foreach($getAllUserTicketHistoryJson as $key => $value){
   $array=$value;
}
```

when I try to var_export($value); the data show like this

```
array ( 'user_id' => '1', 'total_ticket' => '1', )array ( 'user_id' => '2', 'total_ticket' => '50', )array ( 'user_id' => '3', 'total_ticket' => '10', )array ( 'user_id' => '4', 'total_ticket' => '5', )
```

My question is, can I get the data display in one array?

should be like this

```
array("1" => 1, '2' => 50, '3' => 10, '4' => 5)
```

how to get the data become inside one array only?

Comment: You'll need to build that array. You could just use `fetch` and build it in the `while`. Something like `$myarray[$row['user_id']] = $row['total_ticket'];`.

Comment: thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, we need a custom format in foreach.

so the code will be like this

```
$data = array();
foreach($getAllUserTicketHistoryJson as $value){
    $data[$value['user_id']] = number_format((float)($value['total_ticket'] / $getAllTicketRound * 100), 2, '.', '');
}
```

Comment: I think you'd have better performance (minimally) using a regular `fetch` in the function. Your current usage will have to iterate over the data set twice.